# How to install MariaDB alongside with MySQL on localhost?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am learning MariaDB. I want to install MariaDB on my localhost but I don't want to uninstall MySQL on my system.  I have googled it but I didn't get much information so that I can install maria db keeping MySQL as it is. Can u please help me?

Answer (score 1):

> MariaDB is a drop in place replacement for MySQL, but you can also install it alongside MySQL.

[Installing MariaDB Alongside MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/)

Comment: have you try above procedure.?

Comment: No, I did not try it by myself.

Comment: The above guide is not very clear and straight forward.